# Disable a pushButton when another is clicked

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, qt-designer

I'm trying to disable a pushButton when another one is clicked and running an application but I dont really know how to do that (Im a beginner).

I was trying something like

```
 if self.pushButton_IDBOX.clicked.connect(self.sa_h.idbox_test):
    self.pushButton_PTT.setEnabled(False)
```

Thank you for reading my question and your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Method `connect` is not a boolean method. Therefore, your if will not work.
You have to create another method to run test and disable desired button.

```
def onClickIDBOX(self):
    self.sa_h.idbox_test()
    self.pushButton_PTT.setEnabled(False)
```

Then trigger it when `pushButton_IDBOX` is clicked.

```
self.pushButton_IDBOX.clicked.connect(self.onClickIDBOX)
```